# Adding classes to appended content

Tags: jquery

Hey all,
I'm just going to jump right in and describe the issue. JS fiddles are provided to help give you an understanding. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
SEE LINK IN THE COMMENTS FOR WORKING FILE
```

### **1. The Functions**

**Function 1: Adding Multiple Registrations**

The user can add additional registrations form, to complete more then 1 registration simultaniously. 
[JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/orrpatrick/BmmC6/)

**Function 2: Defining the type of Program**

The user can select from multiple types of program registrations available. Upon Selecting a Program it fetches the appropriate form from an external file. [JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/orrpatrick/URGsP/)

### **2. The Problem**

When the program type is assigned to a registration form it returns the data in a div with a specific class. This is obviously a problem because it will return that data to ALL the divs with that class. *If you add multiple registrations then there will be multiple divs with this class.*

This div is grabbed in the first function when the registration form is initially added.

### **3. Solution Needed**

I need to dynamically add numbers into the class of this div, each time a new program is added. This will make each div unique and eliminate the problem.

```
<div class="reg"></div> 
<div class="reg"></div> 
<div class="reg"></div> 
<div class="reg"></div>
```

Ideally it should be something like this:

```
<div class="reg1"></div>
<div class="reg2"></div>
<div class="reg3"></div>
<div class="reg4"></div>
```

I don't have the slightest clue how to get started with this, but it would have to be part of the original function.

Comment: Way to clearly organize your post.  This is a *very* nice post to read.

Comment: to be honest, i'm struggling to work out what the issue is. What's the link between registration forms and program registrations? What are the checkboxes ion the second jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey Guys, 
Sorry I can't show you the page, its a wordpress site and is only in preview right now so you'd need the password

Comment: @alastair pitts:
you have to add a program registration(it appends the first part of the form), before you can define the type of program it is(the second part of the form).

Comment: Here is a working example:
http://www.patrickorr.ca/test/page-accomodationspartners-booking1.php

sorry about the crude styles.

Comment: So the problem is that clicking one registration's checkbox changes all registrations?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that clicking one registration's checkbox changes all the registrations, you just need to scope your selectors better. For example, imagine that each registration looks something like this:

```
<div class='registration'>
   ... a bunch of stuff
   <input type='checkbox' class='blah' /> 
</div>
```

Now you have a handler like this to capture clicks on those checkboxes:

```
$('.registration input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function(){ 

   // figure out which checkbox was checked and whatever
   // but only affect the registration that holds the checkbox:
   var AffectedRegistration = $(this).closest('.registration');

   // do something smart with the affected registration...
});
```

Note: if you post your actual code here you might get more tailored help, but I think this will get you going.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I had no idea that I could use .live or .closest.
I want to put a line of code in that unselects all the other checkboxes should the user select more then one. Is there something that is the opposite of .live that I can use on the same input selector?

Comment: @patrck, that's pretty easy with the [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) traverser/selector. You might use something like this inside my function, where `this` is the clicked checkbox: `$(this).filter(':checked').siblings('input:checked').attr('checked', false);`. Final note: if they should only have one selected, use radio buttons instead!